# Error when using pipe operator and grep in subprocess.check_output to list out Kubernetes pod names

Tags: python, kubernetes, grep, subprocess, pipe

Currently using Kubernetes in a project of mine and am trying to use a Python script to fetch the pod names.

For example, let's say my pod names begin with `frontend`, `backend`, `queue`, and `service`. The pod names themselves will have a string of characters after these names, and I've found the following command lists out all of them:

`$ kubectl get pods --no-headers -o custom-columns=":metadata.name"`

And again, for example, let's say this command returns the following:

```
frontend-d4nkg4nj4-69420
backend-pr4nk3dbr0-z1337
queue-1mf40r3kt-a1b2c
service-101r1pb0z0-g0t3m
```

I found that using the `grep` command will give me the name of a specific pod:

```
$ kubectl get pods --no-headers -o custom-columns=":metadata.name" | grep "service"
service-101r1pb0z0-got3m
```

So I wrote the following Python script in order to store the pod names in a list:

```py
import subprocess

services = ["frontend", "backend", "queue", "service"]
pod_names = []

def get_name(pod_name):
    res = subprocess.check_output([
            "kubectl",
            "get",
            "pods",
            "--no-headers",
            "-o",
            "custom-columns=\":metadata.name\"",
            "|",
            "grep",
            "\"" + pod_name + "\""
        ])
    return res

print("pod_names before: " + str(pod_names))
for service in services:
    pod_names += get_name(service)
print("pod_names after: " + str(pod_names))
```

However, I get these errors:

```
Error from server (NotFound): pods "|" not found
Error from server (NotFound): pods "grep" not found
Error from server (NotFound): pods "\"frontend\"" not found

--traceback info omitted for brevity--

    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['kubectl', 'get', 'pods', '--no-headers', '-o', 'custom-columns=":metadata.name"', '|', 'grep', '"frontend"']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

It seems as if `|`, `grep`, and `frontend` are being passed as arguments to the `kubectl` command instead of being piped to another. How shall I resolve this?

Tried looking at the documentation for `check_output` and found mentions of potentially using `stdout=PIPE` and `stderr=PIPE` but I'm a novice with programming languages and as such don't exactly know how to use these.

Comment: Pipes are shell syntax, not program arguments.